# How to connect python-cgi with dynamodb?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, cgi

I have created a registration page using python cgi.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn2ud.png)

- Now, i want to connect this page with a Dynamodb. so as the user registers his username and password that will be stored in
     **Dynamodb**.
- Then next on registering(on submit) the form it should display the data in the table format of the users who registred(nothing but it should display database from Dynamodb).

How can i acheieve this?? 
Can anyone help me out?